# How to order a MySQL query by range?

Tags: mysql, select, range

Is there a pure MySQL way of ordering elements by range? So let´s say I have table "products" with two columns for prices, one is the old price, one the new one. I now want to select all products and order them by the range of the previous price and the current price. So actually something like `ORDER BY (previous_price - current_price)`. Is there any way to do that or do I need to use a programming language to reorder the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you propose. But then the SQL way:

You select a field called `price`_range that equals `previous_price - current_price`:

```
SELECT (previous_price-current_price) as price_range
```

And then you order it:

```
ORDER BY price_range
```

Comment: I don't really think this is what OP meant to do. Rather, OP trying to do like `order by value between val1 and val2`